# Return value in array that first satisfies condition

Tags: node.js

Sorry, very new to node.js

I want to return a value from an array that first satisfies a condition. See the minimal example below:

```
var urlExists = require('url-exists');
arr = ['http://123123123.com/', 'https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.yahoo.com/']
const found = arr.find(url => urlExists(url, function(err, exists) { return exists } ));
// expecting google.com
```

Not really sure how to have `urlExists(...)` evaluate to `true`.

Comment: And what is going wrong?

Comment: `urlExists` is not a sync function so it is impossible to have a `true` as sync return, so you need to change your code to an async style

Comment: @Manuel I don't know how to change to an async style and return only the first url that exists. I can see how async style could return all urls that exist but not the first one. Any pointers on how to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's an [alternative approach](https://jsbin.com/cehatubawi/1/edit?js,console) that returns the first existing url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here. First, you can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your array of URLs to an array of Promises which either reject or resolve depending on whether calling `urlExists` errors or not for a given URL.

Once you have an array of promises, you can pass that into a call to [`Promise.all()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Promise.all%20mdn&oq=Promise.all%20mdn&aqs=chrome..69i57.4383j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which will return a new promise. When this promise resolves, it will contain an array of the form `[[url1, existsStatus1], ...]`, which you can then use `.find()` on to find the first occurrence where `existsStatus` is true:

```
const urlExists = require('url-exists');
const arr = ['http://123123123.com/', 'https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.yahoo.com/'];

const urlPromise = Promise.all(arr.map(
  url => new Promise((res, rej) => urlExists(url, (err, exists) => err ? rej(err) : res([url, exists])))
));
urlPromise.then((arr) => {
  const [found] = arr.find(([,exists]) => exists) || [];
  console.log(found); // URL found, undefined if nothing found
}).catch((err) => { // error with handling one of the URLs 
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll have to study it now. EDIT: Great explanation as well

Comment: @CPak no. worries, shoot me a message/comment if you need further clarification on anything.

Comment: It looks like the promise is resolving to `true` with my real urls that don't exist: `'http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-200/tsv/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.200.entrez.tsv.gz'`. How would I need to modify the promise to resolve it to `false`?

Comment: @CPak hm, when I run the above code with `'http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-200/tsv/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.200.entrez.tsv.gz'` it seems to be resolving to false on my end

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get it to work using your answer as a template, but switching to `urllib` and using `urllib.request`. The key to my solving it was your breaking down each step.